# Prevent Laravel 5 from implicitly assigning default values when inserting records into MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I come from Rails background and I'm playing around with Laravel 5, I made a `CartItem` model and all the columns should be `NOT NULL` by default. However, If I don't assign some of the attributes, say: `user_id`, Laravel will insert `0` for me, I don't know if this is considered a feature or a bug, since this behavior will hide some flaws or mistakes.

If I forget to assign any NOT NULL attribute, I expect to get Integrity Constraints Violation from MySQL, but Laravel will never let it happen. And if Laravel inserts default value to `NOT NULL` columns, then what's the point to even mark a db column as `NOT NULL`, the framework wouldn't help me to protect this integrity anyway. I guess there must be a way to gently disable this feature, please show me the path, thanks.

More details:

My `CartItem` table looks like this:

```
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('cart_items', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->integer('product_id');
                $table->decimal('unit_price', 11, 2);
                $table->integer('quantity');
                $table->decimal('subtotal', 11, 2);
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();

                $table->index('user_id');
                $table->index('product_id');
            });
        }
```

and in Tinker I can do this:

```
    >>> \App\CartItem::create([])
    =>  {
           updated_at: "2015-06-21 06:57:31",
           created_at: "2015-06-21 06:57:31",
           id: 8
       }
```

this results in a row in my db with all `NOT NULL` columns set to 0 or 0.00, and I've checked my db, all these columns are set to not null and default to `None`.

Comment: far as I know, laravel doesn't assign default values. its your database that assigns default values. have you rechecked your db?

Comment: Never use default values. Ever

Comment: +1 @Salar, I don't think Laravel will assign default values. If you try to insert a null value in a column that does not accept null values it will throw an SQL error.

Drew Pierce why are you saying that? Default values provide some kind of fallback and protects your application from throwing errors/exceptions.

Comment: Have you tried this from your controller ? Secondly am not sure this is correct: 
    >>> \App\CartItem::create([]); you passing empty arry to create method

Comment: The issue is you are passing an empty array to create method here:


      App\CartItem::create([])


Should try this instead:


     \App\CartItem::create([
         'name'=>'frank'
])

Comment: @Digitlimit I intended to pass empty array to creat method to demonstrate how Laravel assigns default values to NOT NULL columns without any feedback to me.

Comment: If I forget to assign any NOT NULL attribute, I expect to get Integrity Constraints Violation from MySQL, but Laravel will never let it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, Laravel 5 doesn't assign default values to NOT NULL columns, but it did turn 'strict' mode off by default.

Here is a snippet from config/database.php:

```
    'mysql' => [
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict'    => false,
            ],
```

By changing `'strict'` form `false` to `true`, I happily saw MySQL throwing exceptions as I expected.

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that the problem is not in Laravel but most likely in MySQL configuration.

Depending on your operating system find `my.cnf` or `my.ini` MySQL configuration file and add `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` to `sql-mode` value.

E.g. before edit:
`sql-mode=”NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION”`

After edit:
`sql-mode=”STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION”`

You have to restart mysql after saving the configuration file and everything will probably work as expected.